# Glide - Rounded Corner size different

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-glide

I want to make 4dp rounded top corners image in a dialog.

[image]

But when I gave 4dp(change to pixel), The imgae was made like this.

[image]

The bottom corners are background drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="4dp" />

</shape>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp" />

</shape>
```

I tried like this code. help me plz

```
    private fun initView() {
        val dm = ctx.resources.displayMetrics
        val width = dm.widthPixels - 60
        val radius = dpToPx(4).toFloat()

        window?.run {
            setLayout(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        }

        Glide.with(ctx)
            .load(quizNoticeImage)
            .transform(GranularRoundedCorners(radius, radius, 0f, 0f))
            .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                override fun onLoadFailed(
                    e: GlideException?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<Drawable>?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    noShowAgain()
                    return false
                }

                override fun onResourceReady(
                    resource: Drawable?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<Drawable>?,
                    dataSource: DataSource?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    vBarHorizontal.visible()
                    vBarVertical.visible()
                    tvNoShowAgain.visible()
                    tvClose.visible()
                    return false
                }
            })
            .into(ivQuiz)

        ivQuiz.setOnClickListener(this)
        tvNoShowAgain.setOnClickListener(this)
        tvClose.setOnClickListener(this)
    }
```

I tried glide - overide, shapable imgae etc.. but I can't make this.
The first image is 12dp(change to pixel)

Comment: Example image url is "https://ifh.cc/g/XxQmXH.png"

Answer (score 0):

You should try defining the alertDialog like this:

```
val alertDialog : AlertDialog =  MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, R.style.MyRounded_MaterialComponents_MaterialAlertDialog)  // for fragment you can use getActivity() instead of this
```

and style like this:

```
<style name="MyRounded.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog" 
    parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">

    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">
        @style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CustomDialog.Rounded
    </item>
    <item name="colorSurface">
        @color/YOUR_COLOR
    </item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CustomDialog.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">
        rounded
    </item>
    <item name="cornerSize">
        4dp
    </item>
</style>
```